# Override field arguments in inherited django models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I installed a django app and want to limit the choices on a foreign key:

```
class InstalledModel(models.Model):
    ...
    base_field = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)

class MyModel(InstalledModel):
    """
    Somehow use limit_choices_to in base_field
    """
```

I know fields cannot be altered in inherited models, but was wondering if this is also true with its arguments giving that it doesn't seem to alter the serialization and initialization of the model itself.

Comment: Wouldn't using `models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)` work? Keeps them loosely coupled though.

Comment: It works, but it lets you choose from all instances of AnotherModel, which I want to limit to only certain instances.

Comment: What about `Field.choices`? They can be dynamic, but isn't recommended.

Comment: Could work as well, the problem is that I can't seem to set it in MyModel given it is inheriting from InstalledModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a property as the `limit_choices_to` argument, e.g.:

```
class InstalledModel(models.Model):
    @property    
    def another_model_choices(self):
        if isinstance(self, MyModel):
            return {'some_condition': True}
        return None

    base_field = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, limit_choices_to=another_model_choices)
```